# SP 2013 - Content Search WebPart with Refiner - Auto apply a default refiner

Tags: 2013, search, content-search-web-part, refinement-panel

I have a page with content search webpart and refiner webpart attached to it. The content search webpart shows data for many years. I have a refinement panel which shows all the years. Now i want a year to be selected in the refinement panel whenever the page loads and subsequently the Content search webpart should show the refined data.